# Mapping dynamically private IPs on a DNS server to a different cidr block

Tags: domain-name-system, nat

I need to map private IPs (i.e. 172.16.0.0/16) of AWS managed services like RDS or Elasticache to a different CIDR block i.e. 172.17.0.0/16 in the way that when a user asks the DNS instead to receive the real DNS server i.e. 172.16.0.120 receive 172.17.0.0/16. It will be job of a NAT that the user will connect to translate those.

Is there a services that can do this? I've not found anything

Comment: See BIND9 views if you're running BIND, otherwise I'd suggest completing the question with the relevant information.

Comment: Have a look at `dnsmasq`.